# Django 3: get_object_or_404 for UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I have a problem:
I'd like to update a specific data/product, but a can't use **get_object_or_404**

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import (
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)

from product.models import Product
from pages.forms import ProductForm

def ProductUpdateView(request, pk): 
    # queryset = Product.objects.all()[0].pk_id <-- I tried this
    # queryset = Product.objects.get() <-- and this

    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    product1 = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    #product1 = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk) <-- and this
     
    if request.method == 'POST':

        productUpdate_form = ProductForm(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES,instance=request.product1))
        # Check to see the form is valid
        if productUpdate_form.is_valid(): # and profile_default.is_valid() :
            # Sava o produto
            productUpdate_form.save()
            # Registration Successful! messages.success
            messages.success(request, 'Produto Modificado com Sucesso')
            #Go to Index
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            # One of the forms was invalid if this else gets called.
            print(productUpdate_form.errors)

    else:
        # render the forms with data.
        productUpdate_form = ProductForm(instance=request.product1)
    
    
    context = {'productUpdate_form': productUpdate_form,}
    return render(request, 'base/update.html',context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from pages.views import (ProductListView,
                        ProductUpdateView,
                        ProductDeleteView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('listProduct/', ProductListView, name='listProduct'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', ProductUpdateView, name='product-update'), <--this link is ok
]
```

**Error:**

AttributeError at /1/update/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'product1'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/update/
Django Version:     3.1.1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'product1'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Desktop\PROJETOS\MyDjango\ECAPI\pages\views.py, line 78, in ProductUpdateView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Anaconda3\envs\ECAPI\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.5
Python Path:

['C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Desktop\PROJETOS\MyDjango\ECAPI',
'C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Anaconda3\envs\ECAPI\python38.zip',
'C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Anaconda3\envs\ECAPI\DLLs',
'C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Anaconda3\envs\ECAPI\lib',
'C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Anaconda3\envs\ECAPI',
'C:\Users\rodrigo negao\Anaconda3\envs\ECAPI\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 01 Oct 2020 21:36:44 -0300.

**So,** I can't compare **pk** in **get_object_or_404**, I need it to found and use a specific data/product.

What other way to use **get_object_or_404** or compare link/pk and data/product ?

Help plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is located at the:

```
productUpdate_form = ProductForm(instance=request.product1)
```

the `request` does not contain a `product1` attribute, you simply pass the `product1` object:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import (
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)

from product.models import Product
from pages.forms import ProductForm

def ProductUpdateView(request, pk): 
    product1 = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        productUpdate_form = ProductForm(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES,instance=product1))
        # Check to see the form is valid
        if productUpdate_form.is_valid(): # and profile_default.is_valid() :
            # Sava o produto
            productUpdate_form.save()
            # Registration Successful! messages.success
            messages.success(request, 'Produto Modificado com Sucesso')
            #Go to Index
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            # One of the forms was invalid if this else gets called.
            print(productUpdate_form.errors)

    else:
        # render the forms with data.
        productUpdate_form = ProductForm(instance=product1)
    
    
    context = {'productUpdate_form': productUpdate_form,}
    return render(request, 'base/update.html',context)
```

This is however not an `UpdateView`: this is not a class-based view, and it does not subclass from `UpdateView`.

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `product_update_view`, not <s>`ProductUpdateView`</s>.

Comment: @RodrigoPereira: can you provide the full traceback? It looks like you use `request` somewhere (else) where you can not use this.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ClassView https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from product.models import Product
from django.contrib import messages
from pages.forms import ProductForm

class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'base/update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Produto Modificado com Sucesso')
        return redirect('index')
 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if 'productUpdate_form' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['productUpdate_form'] = self.get_form()
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         

# urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from pages.views import (ProductListView,
                        ProductUpdateView,
                        ProductDeleteView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('listProduct/', ProductListView, name='listProduct'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product-update'),
]
```